# Sufficient Statistic for a Parameter

Tags: statistics

> Show that the sum of the observations of a random sample of size $n$ from a gamma distribution that has pdf $f(x,\theta)=(1/\theta)e^{-x/\theta}$, $0<x<\infty$, $0<\theta<\infty$, zero elsewhere, is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

This is what I did (but it's wrong, I don't know why):

$$Y=X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n$$

$$f(y,\theta)= \left(\frac{1}{\theta}\right)e^{-y/(\theta)}$$

$$f(x_1;\theta)f(x_2; \theta)\cdots f(x_n,\theta) = \left(\frac{1}{\theta}\right)^n e^{\frac{-x_1-x_2-\cdots-x_n}{\theta}}$$

So...

$$\frac{f(x_1;\theta)f(x_2; \theta)\cdots f(x_n,\theta)}{f(y,\theta)} = \frac{(\frac{1}{\theta})^n e^{\frac{-x_1-x_2-\cdots-x_n}{\theta}}}{(\frac{1}{\theta})e^{-y/\theta}}$$

But that's equal to $(1/\theta)^{n-1}$, which does include $\theta$, so how is it sufficient? I'm sure I did a mistake but I don't know where...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your proposed density for $Y$ is wrong.  The sum does not have an exponential distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
  f \left( x_1, \ldots, x_n ; \theta \right) & = & \theta^{- n} \exp \left( -
  \frac{1}{\theta} \left( x_1 + \cdots + x_n \right) \right)
\end{eqnarray*}
From the last expression, you could see that this is an [exponential family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family)
with parameter $- \frac{1}{\theta}$, sufficient statistic $x_1 + \cdots + x_n$
and normalizing constant $\theta^{- 1}$. You could appeal directly to [Fisher-Neyman factorization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Fisher.E2.80.93Neyman_factorization_theorem) immediately here.

Comment: Thanks a lot...but I'm sorry I think I coppied the wrong question. The pdf is $(1/\theta)e^{-x/\theta}$ instaed of $\theta^n(1-\theta)^x$. I edited my question.

Comment: @Artus That´s even simpler.

Comment: I think you dont need any algebra here. It is obvious that $h(x)=1$ and the other function is not not a function of any single part of $x$

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören That's why it is a single line!

Comment: @Learner Thanks. I actually did try to use the Neyman theorem. Did you look at my answer? I was just wondering where I went wrong. I was trying to show that if we divide $f(x_1; \theta)...f(x_n,\theta)$ by $f(y,\theta)$, then we get a function that does not inlcude theta in it. But when I actually did divide them, the result was $(1/\theta)^{n-1}$ which does include $\theta$. So is it ok if you tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: @Artus This is because $f(y,\theta)$ is not a density (normalizing constant must be raised to the power $n$ to get a density for $y$).